# spawn a thread for each loop from a for each loop of a file array

Tags: java, multithreading

i have a for each loop for file array. For each file there are certain operations performed which are common. There are lot of such files to be processed and its time consuming. I was thinking if java threads can help me achieve higher performance. I am new to java thread programming. Any help needed

Comment: What research have you done?  What have you tried?  What documentation have you read?

Comment: @gray i am asking this question from my mobile. I don't have the code i tried. I will update the question when possible. I have read the tutorial provided by oracle and some sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose FileReader Class contains the logic for processing a single File

```
public class FileReader implements Runnable {

String fileName;

public FileReader(String fileName) {
   this.fileName = fileName;
}

public void run() {

 processFile(fileName);

}

private void processFile(String fileName) {
  // Your logic of processing the file.
}

}
```

Then add the following code to process the files in a directory

You should always use a thread pool to make sure you use the system resources elegantly

```
private static final int THREAD_COUNT = 10;
private static final ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        THREAD_COUNT, THREAD_COUNT, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

for each file you want to process

```
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
  pool.execute(reader);
```

Comment: this answers my question. Thanks. I will implement this and post the working code

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you have to do for each file, and where the bottleneck lies with the processing.  If you're processing is CPU-bound (you have to do alot of calculations on the data read from the file), then creating more threads then you have CPU cores to run them on isn't going to help you.

On the other hand, if your processing happens to be something like "submit the file data to server, wait on response", and submitting your requests concurrently doesn't slow the server down, having a thread per file might help.

Without knowing more about what the processing involves there isn't really a specific recommendation that can be given.

Comment: the operations on file is a file read write operations. It reads the files edits the file and saves it back.

Comment: I would recommend doing some testing to figure out how many threads you can run simultaneously before the extra overhead of managing all the threads ends up slowing you down more then the parall processing speeds things up.  The ThreadPoolExecutor class suggested by @byter would be a good way to limit the number of threads your program uses.